# Using map function to filter a data.frame element with list names

Tags: r, purrr

This is my list

```
mylist <- list(setosa = iris,versicolor = iris, virginica = iris)
```

I have to use `filter` `dplyr` function. But the argument should be the name of the list element that map is interate, because my list is much more bigger:

```
map(mylist, ~ .x %>% filter(Species == 'name_of_(.x)_element_list')
```

I tried to do something like this, but didnt work:

```
map(mylist, ~ .x %>% filter(Species == {{names(.x)}})
```

Any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
map2(mylist, names(mylist), \(l, n) filter(l, Species == n))
```

Edit: Or with a purrr-style lambda function:

```
map2(mylist, names(mylist), ~ filter(.x, Species == .y))
```

Comment: Yeah! purrr-style looks amazing! Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

I think we can also use `imap` function here, but I hope I got what you have in mind correctly. It is very similar to `map2` just as `.x` is iterating on the values and `.y` is iterating on the names (positions):

```
library(purrr)

mylist %>%
  imap(~ .x %>% filter(Species == .y))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `base R`

```
Map(function(x, y) subset(x, Species == y),mylist, names(mylist))
```